# Chrome gradient changes color when items appear over top of it

Tags: css, google-chrome, xpath, overlay, gradient

You can look at the code in question at: https://test.fuzebox.com

Greetings!
I ran across a problem this morning that I've never seen before.  We have a set of dropdown menus in our global nav.  When you mouse over them, they drop "over" the large blue bar.  In Chrome (Win/Mac) the drop down leaves an "impression" on the color of the blue gradient bar.  The problem does not occur if you remove the gradient and just use a solid background color.  I tried pushing some stuff "back" with z-indexes to no avail.  My googling turned up nothing about this type of problem. Below are before and after images.

The DIVs in play are:

- `#fuze-home-blue-bar`
- `#fuze-home-blue-bar-bkgnd`

and the nav dropdown XPath is:

`/html/body[@class='template-document_view portaltype-document site-FuzeBox section-technology icons-on content-id-mobile']/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='fuzeportal-top']/div[@id='fuzeportal-header']/ul[@id='portal-globalnav']/li[@id='portaltab-technology']/ul[@class='submenu']/li[1]`

## Before

[image: BEFORE]

## After

[image: AFTER]

Any suggestions are appreciated.  Doesn't occur in any other browser/OS combo.

Comment: It almost looks like the gradient isn't being honored until the dropdowns conceal it, then that portion is correctly colored...

Comment: Note that the gradient is shifted 85%/100%: background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #0cbef6 85%,#008ce5 100%)  Without the shift, the problem also does not happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sometimes Chrome's hardware acceleration changes colors slightly.  Try this fix... it's magic.

```
#fuze-home-blue-bar {
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: That *is* magic.  I'll have to file that one away in my toolkit.  Thanks

Comment: I also believe that josh.trow is correct. The gradient isn't being applied until after the overlay.  The fix above solved the color change issue, but the gradient remains a mystery...for now.